# Как создать список каждых N-ых элементов из индексов фрейма данных?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, index

Пытаюсь создать список каждых 4-ых элементов (period=4) из индексов DataFrame.

Вот как выглядит `df` (`Timestamp` - имя индексов):

```
                                         Value1   ...             ValueN
Timestamp                                         ...                        
2020-04-14 00:00:00                      1677.65  ...              82.98
2020-04-14 00:01:00                      1676.04  ...              83.02
2020-04-14 00:02:00                      1675.11  ...              83.04
2020-04-14 00:03:00                      1671.00  ...              83.05
2020-04-14 00:04:00                      1675.68  ...              83.05
```

Использую функцию

```
lst = []
lst.append([k for k in df.index.values if not k % period])
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Error: ufunc 'remainder' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('int32')

Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = df.iloc[::4].index
```